# Django redirect with kwargs not working

Tags: django, django-urls

I have seen similar questions, this is not a duplicate. I have a simple redirect that recieves kwargs that is not working and I don't know why. The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) give this example:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

And it is exactly what I'm doing:

```
...
...
return redirect('perfiles:despues_contacto', razon_contacto='donacion', correo_contacto='thrall@gmail.com')
```

The url pattern looks like this:

```
url(r'^gracias_por_contactarnos/(?P<razon_contacto>[-\w]+)/(?P<correo_contacto>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.DespuesContacto.as_view(), name="despues_contacto"),
```

?¿ What am I missing? maybe it is something obvious ... but my eyes are tired of trying to find the error. Is it the regex?

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: @Selcuk `Reverse for 'despues_contacto' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'razon_contacto': u'donacion', 'correo_contacto': u'thrall@gmail.com'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'perfil/gracias_por_contactarnos/(?P<razon_contacto>[-\\w]+)/(?P<correo_contacto>[-\\w]+)/$']` ... looks like its the regex.

Comment: It looks like your correo_contacto regex does not accept @ and dot (.) signs.

Comment: @Selcuk Yup... I'm trying to find a regex that does ... do you have one?

Comment: @Selcuk I'm an ignorant when it comes to regexes.

Comment: Just Google for a regex that matches email addresses. There are many possible combinations you should take into account.

Comment: Looks like its really complex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Very simple.  You only change regular expression of url to it undestand parameter have @ character.

urls.py

```
    url(r'^gracias_por_contactarnos/(?P<razon_contacto>[-\w]+)/(?P<correo_contacto>[\w\-@.]+)/$',
    views.DespuesContacto.as_view(), name='despues_contacto'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. I'll accept this answer. But the regex is incomplete, it needs to accept dots too. Please update it and I'll accept.

Comment: You have to add dots after @ in regex

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the regex was wrong, it didn't accept "@" or "." ... and because it is really difficult to use a regex for emails, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) SO question. I processed the email, then send it to the url, and manually built it again:

```
email_for_url = email.split(".")[0].replace("@", "-")    
return redirect('perfiles:despues_contacto', razon_contacto=razon_contacto, correo_contacto=email_for_url)

...
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
   ....
    email = kwargs["email"].replace("-", "@") + ".com"
```

Comment: What if original email already has `"-"` before `"@"`? It will rebuild wrong email. If you have to do it like this, use more complex identifier for `"@"` i.e. `"--__--"`.